# Has anybody heard anything about a new "Prometheus" movie coming out?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, alien-covenant

I've been keeping up wit the updates for "Prometheus 2".

According to wiki the movie costed $120–130 million to make, which doesn't include marketing costs, and took in 403.4 million dollars so it was a huge success.

Here's the latest on what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(2012_film)#Sequels) stated about a sequel:

> "**Sequel**
>
> On March 17, 2012, Scott said that the film **leaves many questions
>   unanswered** and that these **could be answered in a sequel**. He
>   said, "If we're lucky, there'll be a second part. It does leave you
>   with some nice open questions." Asked whether a sequel would be a
>   direct prequel to Alien, Lindelof said: "If we're fortunate enough to
>   do a sequel ... it will tangentialize even further away from the
>   original Alien." In June 2012, Lindelof said that while plot elements
>   **were deliberately left unresolved so that they could be answered in a sequel**, he and Scott had thoroughly discussed what should be
>   resolved so that Prometheus could stand alone, as a sequel was not
>   guaranteed. Scott said that a sequel would follow Shaw to her next
>   destination, "because if it is paradise, paradise cannot be what you
>   think it is. Paradise has a connotation of being extremely sinister
>   and ominous." Lindelof cast doubt on his participation, and said, "if
>   [Scott] wants me to be involved in something, that would be hard to
>   say no to. At the same time, I do feel like [Prometheus] might benefit
>   from a fresh voice or a fresh take or a fresh thought." Scott said
>   that an additional film would be required to bridge the gap between
>   the Prometheus sequel and Alien. As of August 1, 2012 Fox was pursuing
>   a sequel with Scott, Rapace, and Fassbender involved, and was talking
>   to new writers in case Lindelof did not return. The film would be
>   scheduled for a release no earlier than 2014. In December 2012,
>   Lindelof had decided not to work on a sequel, citing other
>   commitments. In June 2013, Jack Paglen was in negotiations to write
>   the sequel. In October 2013, Scott confirmed that the script was
>   complete, but in **March 2014, Michael Green was hired to rewrite
>   Paglen's script.**

The ending left so much up in the air, and clearly as the article states it's set up for a sequel. The last entry is in March of 2014, over a year ago.

Is there any updated info that anybody has seen on if/when a sequel is coming out?

If you could include links to your sources that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I believe this would be off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update.

There **will be** a direct sequel to 'Prometheus', named ['Alien: Covenant'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant).

Wikipedia describes it as...

> ... the second installment in the 'Alien' prequel series, the sixth
>   installment overall in the 'Alien' film series, and the third
>   installment to be directed by Scott. **The film stars Michael
>   Fassbender, Noomi Rapace, and Guy Pearce, returning in their roles
>   from 'Prometheus',** with newcomers Katherine Waterston, Billy Crudup,
>   Danny McBride, Demián Bichir and James Franco.

Thematically, the goal seems to be to try to link the 'Prometheus' films with the 'Alien' films in order to create a prequel/sequel/original franchise universe akin to Lucasfilm's 'Star Wars' empire.

### <s>There won't be one</s>

It has been [announced](https://deadline.com/2015/09/ridley-scott-reveals-prometheus-2-title-1201548826/) that 'Prometheus' will **not** now be receiving a sequel. The upcoming film by Ridley Scott will be titled ['Alien: Paradise Lost'](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2316204/)  and although it will be set in the same cinematic universe as the earlier film, it will not be directly connected to Prometheus, other than by the same sort of loose bonds that connected Prometheus to the existing Alien Quadrilogy:

> That by itself is practically a spoiler, indicating the film is more
>   directly connected to the Alien universe than was its predecessor.
>   “**Prometheus 2 is not really what it’s going to be,**” Scott said. “It’s
>   going to be Alien: Paradise Lost.” He explained in the interview that
>   the film will be more a prequel to 1979’s Alien, examining the “why
>   and how the beast was invented.” Further, the allusion to the poem by
>   John Milton is intentional, with Scott saying that there will be
>   “really a similarity” between it and the film.

Comment: Thank you for a correct answer. Read the other answer and the comments. Now you see why I'm done here. I'll chat once in awhile, maybe post a question here or there, but no more answers. +1

Comment: @JMFB - Sad to hear that. Note that at the time of the question, the answer below was correct. No-one could have predicted that they'd cancel the sequel quite to dramatically.

Comment: the links were exactly what I put in the comments. He posted links to sites that spoke about alien 5, there was nothing about plot, or specifically mentioning prometheus 5, of course I did a google search before I posted the question here, and stated that in my question. Although Prometheus could have been better, it ended with an amazing cliffhanger. I want to know where she's going, and what she's going to find when she gets there. I think they probably had a problem writing something that would be a fulfilling conclusion, especially at how disappointing prometheus was in some ways.

Comment: Just for posterity, the movie is now called *Alien: Covenant* and will release on May 19, 2017.

Comment: @tobiasvl - I've edited accordingly. For the record, this movie is going to be as precisely as bad as Prometheus.

Comment: @Valorum I won't buy you a beer if you're wrong, to put it like that, but here's to hoping!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are having trouble finding this information- I found it by simply googling "Prometheus 2".  There are entire [sites](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621210840/https://www.prometheus2-movie.com) and individual [pages](https://www.crossmap.com/news/prometheus-2-and-alien-5-release-dates-and-news-neill-blomkamp-talks-about-the-upcoming-alien-5-and-prometheus-2-prometheus-3-will-happen-according-to-nimrod-antal.html) devoted to this topic.

*Prometheus 2* is scheduled to be released in March of 2016.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the pages you linked to. The first one took me to a page that said don't believe any rumours about the sequel. The second one mainly focused on the "Aliens 5" movie and didn't go into any details about Prometheus 2. It did give a projected May 2 2016 release date but didn't say where it got that from and included no quotes or interviews from the upcoming alleged director of the P2 movie. Can you give anything more concrete and authoritative. It's hard to believe that the Wiki page wouldn't be updated if there's that much common knowledge about it as you suspect. Thanks

Comment: @JMFB - I have seen hundreds of wiki pages that refer to events that happened years ago in the future tense.  I did look through the pages I linked, and they seemed relatively up to date (especially the second one).  "Don't believe the rumors" means rumors about the plot and setting of the movie, not rumors that it will be made.  The movie is in the works as we speak.  And again, you can find all kinds of information by simply googling "Prometheus 2".  If you read the first link, you will see that the director of the Alien movie is trying to avoid conflicts with Prometheus 2.

Comment: this is why I'm done with this site for the most part. You get +3 for this answer which is completely incorrect, and used condescending language, I get -8, and then today Richard posts an answer that shows my question was a perfectly valid one. As you stated "there's hundreds of pages", and " "Don't believe the rumors" means rumors about the plot and setting of the movie, not rumors that it will be made. The movie is in the works as we speak." is completely incorrect, it's not in the works, and like I stated when you posted your answer there's an Aliens 5 movie but no prometheus 2.

Comment: @JMFB - Things change.  Apparently things changed quite dramatically since I posted this answer.

Comment: @JMFB - As Richard said, this answer was correct when I wrote it.  I wasn't being condescending, I was verbally expressing that the question could easily have been answered by a little google work.  The other option would have been to downvote the question like everyone else did, but I didn't want to downvote.